# Create a discontinued line chart using Vega lib

Tags: charts, data-visualization, linechart, vega

I am looking to create this kind of chart in Vega:

[image: A basic Excel discontinued line chart]

I carefully read the documentation about marks here:
https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/line/

I read about the **Type-Specific Mark Properties** and about the *defined* property and it seemed like what I need. But I have no idea how to use this property.

I have my marks defined like so:

```
'marks': [
      {
        'name': 'expected_sales',
        'description': 'The sales line',
        'type': 'line',
        'defined': 'false', // this I added based on the documentation
        'from': {
          'data': 'SalesData'
        },
        'zindex': 100,
        'encode': { ... }
      }
 ]
```

But this apparently doesn't work. the line is still continued. I have to mention that the data points that I get don't have `null` values, but `0.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that sales might be $0 at some point, it is better to deferentiate between `0` values and `null` values.

That said, because null values are defined as `0.0` in the dataset, `defined` property has to be true for all other points except when value is `0.0`

In the below example, `"defined": {"signal": "datum.v !== 0.0"}` is used to conditionally assign `"defined"` property to false if value `"datum.v"` is 0.0

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"u": 1, "v": 28}, {"u": 2, "v": 12.0},
        {"u": 3, "v": 0.0}, {"u": 4, "v": 10},
        {"u": 5, "v": 36}, {"u": 6, "v": 44}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width",
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "u"}
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": false,
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "v"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"scale": "xscale", "orient": "bottom", "grid": true},
    {"scale": "yscale", "orient": "left"}

  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "from": {"data": "table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "stroke": {"value": "#652c90"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "u"},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "v"},
          "defined": {"signal": "datum.v !== 0.0"},
          "interpolate": {"value": "linear"},
          "strokeWidth": {"value": 4},
          "strokeDash": {"value": [1,0]},
          "strokeCap": {"value": "square"},
          "opacity": {"value": 1}
        },
        "hover": {
          "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: so then, for `null` values, we just substitute 0.0 for null?